# Why did Harry Potter look for Peter Pettigrew when he saw his name on the Marauder's Map in the third Harry Potter film?

Tags: harry-potter

Why did Harry Potter look for Peter Pettigrew when he saw his name on the Marauder's Map in the third Harry Potter film? He could have just assumed that Peter Pettigrew was a ghost like the other Hogwarts ghosts.

Comment: At the very least he'd want to go see Pettigrew's ghost..

Comment: *Why not?* When the one person who was directly linked to his dead parents shows up on a map, who wouldn't go out looking for him?

Answer (score 6):

Because Harry is curious.

He's been told that Peter Pettigrew is dead, he's never seen him on the map before and no-one has ever mentioned him.

Further more, he's associated the name 'Pettigrew' with 'Sirius' and his parents and he really wants to know the truth.